# grails using pagination with form submission

Tags: forms, grails, pagination

I am new to grails, right now I'm stuck with a page of form submission, which contains the pagination inside it. My purpose is to create a form submission of 2 or 3 pages which made from pagination. If I were in page 1, selected the input which used g:radio, then I go to page 2 and checked for the other input but if I want to go back to page 1, everything must be the same as I checked before i go to page 2. Could anyone please give me a guide how to do it? Thank you and welcome for any responses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649801/jquery-ui-tabs-multiple-form-submissions-with-on-click have a look at jquery-ui tab form examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is called "Spring WebFlow". Each flow has a start and one or more ends and unlimited number of steps in between. Grails has a nice DSL to define flows, transitions and more.

Spring flow for Grails is well documented at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#webflow.

Comment: Thank you Defectus. let me check it.

Comment: It takes some time to master it :-)